# Xcode repetitive falling images

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm making a game that involves falling images. I have 6 images and I want each one to fall randomly (ex. The $1 bill will be falling and then a $5 bill (or whatever randomly generated image) falling either beside it or right behind it (The iOS game Sky Burger by: NimbleBit LLC or Crazy Goats by: Barry Calvagna are a couple of examples)). Can anybody help me? This is all the code I have so far

```
-(void)moneyDrop {
money.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"$1 (bill).png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"$5 (bill).png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"$20 (bill).png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"$50 (bill).png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"$100 (bill).png"],nil]; }
```

I have not necessarily worked with falling image, unless you count a Flappy Bird remake or a Ball Pong game, so please excuse the lack of code. If my question doesn't make any since, I will re-word it.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it sounds to me like you want multiple UIImageViews each with a different image, not a single UIImageView with an array of animationImages.

For making things move, you can use NSTimer.

```
- (void)start {
    mainTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05  target:self selector:@selector(mainTimerLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)mainTimerLoop {
    NSLog(@"Loop");
    //In here, you can assign random images to and adjust the centers of money image views.
}
```

You could make a function like this to return an image.

```
- (UIImage *)moneyImageForRandomInt:(int)random {
    if (random == 0) return [UIImage imageNamed:@"$1 (bill).png"];
    if (random == 1) return [UIImage imageNamed:@"$5 (bill).png"];
    if (random == 2) return [UIImage imageNamed:@"$20 (bill).png"];
    if (random == 3) return [UIImage imageNamed:@"$50 (bill).png"];
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"$100 (bill).png"];
}
```

And use a function like this to assign a random image to a UIImageView.

```
- (void)assignRandomImageToMoneyImageView:(UIImageView *)moneyImageView {

    moneyImageView.image = [self moneyImageForRandomInt:arc4random() % 5];
}
```

This is how I would go about it, anyway.

Comment: I noticed that when I create a IBOutlet with a UImageView of moneyImageView, I get "Local declaration of 'moneyImageView' hides instance variable". How would I connect the image in the Storyboard to the code then?